# MySQL How to select orders containing set of product types

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 4 tables below:

orders

| id | items_quantity |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 4 |

items

| id | order_id | product_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 | 4 |
| 6 | 3 | 4 |

table products

| id | product_type_id | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Red Bull |
| 2 | 2 | Dairy Pure |
| 3 | 3 | Aquafina |
| 4 | 4 | M&M's |

table product_types

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Beverage |
| 2 | Milk |
| 3 | Water |
| 4 | Food |

I am having trouble finding a solution to get all orders containing beverage items. Those orders can contain milk and water items but without food items. Expected result will be order with id 1.
I have tried this query but I still get orders containing food items.

```
SELECT "orders".* FROM "orders"
INNER JOIN "items" ON "items"."order_id" = "orders"."id"
INNER JOIN "products" ON "products"."id" = "items"."product_id"
INNER JOIN "product_types" ON "product_types"."id" = "products"."product_type_id"
WHERE (product_types.name != 'Food')
GROUP BY product_types.name, orders.id HAVING (product_types.name = 'Beverage')
```

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result as tabular text

Comment: `HAVING SUM(product_types.name = 'Beverage')`

Comment: In MySQL you should use backticks rather than quotes or nothing at all where not using reserved words

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried to explicitly filter the product_types you want to appear in your query to achieve id=1 containing beverage items:

```
SELECT `orders`.* FROM `orders`
INNER JOIN `items` ON `items`.`order_id` = `orders`.`id`
INNER JOIN `products` ON `products`.`id` = `items`.`product_id`
INNER JOIN `product_types` ON `product_types`.`id` = `products`.`product_type_id`
WHERE `product_types`.`name` != 'Food'
AND `product_types`.`name` = 'Beverage'
GROUP BY `product_types`.`name`;
```

Output:

```
+----+----------------+
| id | items_quantity |
+----+----------------+
| 1  | 3              |
+----+----------------+
1 row in set (0.04 sec)
```